# GoogleAuth javascript API not detecting already loggedin users

Tags: javascript, api, google-oauth

I'm using the Google Javascript API, and it's working for direct logins, although it isn't able to detect users that are already logged in on the page load.
Here is my code:

```
loadGoogleAPI() {
        const script = document.createElement("script");
        let $this = this;
        script.onload = () => {
            gapi.load('client:auth2', () => {
                gapi.client.init({
                    apiKey: '',
                    clientId: '',
                    scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses profile',
                    accessType: 'offline'
                }).then(() => {
                   let auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
                   console.log(auth2);
                    auth2.currentUser.listen((val) => {
                        this.setState({auth2: this.state.auth2});
                        console.log(val)
                    });
                    if (auth2.isSignedIn.get()) {
                        console.log(1);
                        this.state.auth2.signIn();
                    }
                    auth2.attachClickHandler(Style.parse('sign-in-button'), {}, function(user) {
                        console.log(user);
                    }, function (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    });
                    this.setState({auth2})
                });
            });
        };
        script.src = "https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js";
        document.head.appendChild(script);
    }
```

Comment: What are the outputs? Where are you putting the code? How do you know the login worked and isn't being detected?

Comment: It just outputs null on the initial load, I know the login is working because the login successfully goes through and returns a proper user object.I'm using react and just doing the initial signIn through attaching the click handler to a button.The code is in a class, it's all firing--thus how I'm able to signin and view it working.